# iOS 16 custom Focus unexpectedly silences Messages app

Tags: ios, messages, focus

iOS 16 allows to create **custom Focus** where you can select to either **silence certain apps** or, as already available in iOS 15, **allow certain apps**.

I set up a custom Focus where I silenced 3 specific work apps. The Messages app is not on that list.

However, when the custom Focus is on, I do not receive messages on my lock screen anymore and the other users, as I enabled to share that information, get the information in Messages that the user (me) has focus set and will not receive the message.

Is this supposed to be like that? Is this another Apple move? As in the Automations that are not automatic? Am I missing something?

Edit:
It turns out that iMessages from Groups are still received and alerted as usual but iMessages from a single person are muted and hidden

Comment: Have you also set the "People" section to be unblocked by default, like you did with the "Apps" section

Comment: Yes. I selected "Silence Notifications From" and did not select anyone. As per common logic I would now expect none to be silenced